# rails view link_to

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, link-to

Thanks for your time!

I had a code :

```
<link href="/stylesheets/show.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div id="body-container">
        <div id="left-column">
                <ul id="report-list">
                        <% for report in @reports %>
                            <li><%= link_to( report, {:controller => 'loadreport',
                                                      :action => 'get_report_content',
                                                      :test_name => report} )%></li>
                        <% end %>
                </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="right-column">

    </div>
</div>
```

The `link_to` method will generate html tags like this :

```
<a href="/loadreport/get_report_content?name=Test1">Test1</a>
```

I want to make some decoration on `tag a`. So in CSS file, I got this codes :

```
a:link { text-decoration: none;}

a:hover {text-decoration-color: #adff2f;}
```

It failed to add these decorations to `tag a`. I think it because `tag a` is generated by rails `link_to` method. We don't have `tag a` ahead of time. Am I right? Then how can I achieve this?

Comment: You're not right, there must be something else. All the browser gets is HTML + CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
a { text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { color: #adff2f; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works. I've just found out I put the CSS code in the wrong CSS file. So my hypothesis is totally wrong.